# how to find all the double characters in a string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I am trying to get a count of all the **double** characters in a string using C#,i.e `"ssss"` should be two doubles not three doubles.

For example right now i have to do a for loop in the string like this

```
string s="shopkeeper";
for(int i=1;i<s.Length;i++) if(s[i]==s[i-1]) d++;
```

the value of `d` at the end should be `1`

Is there a shorter way to do this? in linq or regex? and what are the perfomance implications, what is the most effective way? Thanks for your help

> I have read [[How to check repeated letters in a string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133022/how-to-check-repeated-letters-in-a-string-c-sharp)] and
>   it's helpful, but doesn't address double characters, i am looking for
>   double characters

Comment: I think, it's the best way (simple and fast)

Comment: @Backs thanks i have noticed the for loop is faster than regex, i now need a linq version of this to do a clear comparison on which method to choose

Comment: If the performance is crucial you should choose your `for` loop. If you're interested, one of possible LINQ solutions `s.Zip(s.Skip(1), (c1, c2) => c1 == c2).Count(b => b)` outperforms Regex, but still slower than your simple loop.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser, your linq doesnt give the correct answer, did you test it?

Comment: I did, it works for me

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser, i did this
`s="shhopkeeperssss";
s.Zip(s.Skip(1), (c1, c2) => c1 == c2).Count(b => b);`
and i got 5 instead of 4

Comment: You should stick with your solution. Linq cant be faster than this. Linq is no voodoo magic but normal code under its hood.

Comment: well, your `for` loop also gives 5. `ssss` is a 3 pairs of `s`, not 2, be careful :)

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser, thanks for bringing that up, even the for loop wont give the correct answer, only the regex brings the correct one!
i will have to tweak the for to work for `"ssss"` as two doubles and not three

Comment: here's the tweak you want: `if (s[i] == s[i - 1]) { d++; i++; }`

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser, thanks alot, will have to go with the for loop, because am running it on an array of strings and the array can be very big.

Comment: @Manoz its not a duplicate of that, because i am looking for double characters not repeated characters...

Comment: What should a string with 3 `"s"`'s give? Just one pair?

Comment: @Enigmativity it should give 1

Answer (score 1):

Try following Regex to extract any double characters: `"(.)\1"`

UPD: simple example:

```
foreach (var match in Regex.Matches("shhopkeeper", @"(.)\1"))
   Console.WriteLine(match);
```

Comment: It will find first double letter, won't it?

Comment: @Backs In C# you can extract all the occurrences. Different ones.

Comment: @Backs  expanded an answer with example.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser, your answer works perfect, i just need to replace my for loop with this one line 
`d+=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(s,@"(.)\1").Count;`
but i need to compare with a linq version of this, then i do a performance comparison to come up with the final solution.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser - Good answer. This works nicely to compute the actual value required - `Regex.Matches(word, @"(.)\1").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Length / 2).Sum()`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var doubles =
    text
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            text.Take(1).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList(),
            (a, c) =>
            {
                if (a.Last().Last() == c)
                    a[a.Count - 1] += c.ToString();
                else
                    a.Add(c.ToString());
                return a;
            })
        .Select(x => x.Length / 2)
        .Sum();
```

I gives me these results:

```
"shopkeeper" -> 1
"beekeeper" -> 2
"bookkeeper" -> 3
"boookkkeeeper" -> 3
"booookkkkeeeeper" -> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to mention that there is no "natural" LINQ solution to this problem, so every standard LINQ based solution will be ugly and highly inefficient compared to a simple `for` loop.

However there is a LINQ "spirit" solution to this and similar problems, like the linked [How to check repeated letters in a string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133022/how-to-check-repeated-letters-in-a-string-c-sharp) or if you want for instance finding not **double**s, but let say **triple**s, **quadruple**s etc.

The common sub problem is, given a some sequence of elements, generate a new sequence of `(value, count)` pair groups for the consecutive elements having one and the same value.

It can be done with a custom extension method like this (the name of the method could be different, it's not essential for the point):

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> resultSelector, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer = null)
    {
        if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            for (bool more = e.MoveNext(); more;)
            {
                var value = e.Current;
                int count = 1;
                while ((more = e.MoveNext()) && comparer.Equals(e.Current, value)) count++;
                yield return resultSelector(value, count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this function in combination with standard LINQ, one can easily solve the original question:

```
var s = "shhopkeeperssss";
var countDoubles = s.Zip((value, count) => count / 2).Sum();
```

but also

```
var countTriples = s.Zip((value, count) => count / 3).Sum();
```

or

```
var countQuadruples = s.Zip((value, count) => count / 4).Sum();
```

or the question from the link

```
var repeatedChars = s.Zip((value, count) => new { Char = value, Count = count })
    .Where(e => e.Count > 1);
```

etc.