# I need assistance with a function

Tags: c#, project

So I've been struggling for a while to write a function in C#
that receives a string array of words (that were split before being received by the function from a string into a word array).

So what I've been trying to make is a function that checks if except from `words[0]` (words is the name of the word array) in the entire array if there is a letter which is displayed more than 3 times (3 is a minimum).

For example, this sentence:

> **Why llll ddd ssssssss !!!!!!!?**

Because no letter exists more than 3 times in a word - a word like that doesn't exist.
the base of the function looks like this :

```
public bool MultipleCheck(string[] words)
{

}
```

What I came up with this far... it has mistakes I know... I didn't fix it yet:

```
public bool AttachmentsCheck(string[] words)
{

    string currentWord;
    int wordCounter = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        currentWord = words[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < currentWord.Length; j++)
        {
            char[] wordArr = currentWord.ToCharArray();
            for (int k=0; k < wordArr.Length; k++)
            {
                if (wordArr[k]==wordArr[wordArr.Length-k])
                {
                    wordCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (wordCounter => 3)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So, what have you come up with so far? Some code, perhaps?

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code sample. What exception are you getting?

Comment: Help me please... I gave you what I tried to come up with...

Comment: I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133022/how-to-check-repeated-letters-in-a-string-c-sharp) should help you

Comment: "_Because no letter exists more than 3 times in a word - a word like that doesn't exist._" I beg to differ. How about this word: `senseless`? Or how about this word: `unintentionally`? You just claimed words like these don't exist. ;-)

Comment: Ok so I meant 3 letters next to each other...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check repeated letters in a string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133022/how-to-check-repeated-letters-in-a-string-c-sharp)

Comment: Why does `MultipleCheck` not actually do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an extension method to determine if a word has a run of n consecutive characters:

```
public static class StringExt {
    public static bool WordHasConsecutive(this string word, int n) {
        if (word.Length <= 1)
            return false;
        if (n < 2)
            return true;
        if (word.Length >= n) {
            var ch = word[0];
            var count = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; ++i) {
                if (word[i] == ch) {
                    if (++count == n)
                        return true;
                }
                else {
                    ch = word[i];
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The answer is very simple, simply return the words that have a run of at least length 3:

```
var ans = words.Where(w => w.WordHasConsecutive(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will work**

```
private static Tuple<bool, string> ValidateWord(string[] words)
{
    bool foundResult = false;
    List<string> all3CharWords = new List<string>();
    string wordWith3SameChar = string.Empty;

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        var resultTuple = ValidateWord(word);
        if (resultTuple.Item1)
        {
            foundResult = true;
            all3CharWords.Add(resultTuple.Item2);
        }
    }

    if (foundResult)
    {
        wordWith3SameChar = String.Join(";", all3CharWords.ToArray());
    }

    return new Tuple<bool, string>(foundResult, wordWith3SameChar);
}


private static Tuple<bool, string> ValidateWord(string words)
{
    bool foundResult = false;
    string wordWith3SameChar = string.Empty;
    List<string> traversedChars = new List<string>();
    for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!traversedChars.Contains(words[i].ToString()))
        {
            string tripleChar = $"{words[i]}{words[i]}{words[i]}";
            if (words.Contains(tripleChar))
            {
                foundResult = true;
                wordWith3SameChar = words;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return new Tuple<bool, string>(foundResult, wordWith3SameChar);
}
```

**By calling as below you will get the answer**

```
var resultTuple = ValidateWord("Why llll ddd ssssssss".Split(' ').ToArray());
if (resultTuple.Item1)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The following words have 3 similar charecters: " + resultTuple.Item2);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No words has consecutive 3 similar charecters.");
}
```