# Cannot check a string against a char array through Linq method Contains() because the array isn't of type String, conversion to String type fails

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, char, conditional-statements

I've tried converting the local `charItem` variables I check against to the String type but that didn't seem to solve the issue. What can I do?

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    public static string ValidatePassword(string myPassword)
    {
        char[] alphabetUpper  =   {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
        char[] alphabetLower  =   {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        char[] digits     =   {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
        char[] symbols    =   {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '=', '_', '-', '{', '}', '[', ']', ':', ';', '\"', '\'', '?', '<', '>', ',', '.'};
        
        ushort countUpper   =   0;  // Tracks uppercase characters.
        ushort countLower   =   0;  // Tracks lowercase characters.
        ushort countDigits  =   0;  // Tracks digits.
        ushort countSymbols =   0;  // Tracks symbols.
        
        bool repeatingCharacters = false; // Tracks repeated characters.
        
        if (myPassword.Length >= 6 || myPassword.Length <= 24)  // First, check if the length matches the range. If this succeeds, check for uppercase.
        {
            foreach (char charItem in myPassword)
            {
                if (alphabetUpper.Any(charItem.Contains))       // This checks for uppercase.
                {countUpper++;} 
            }
```

...

```
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ValidatePassword("abc123ABC"));
    }
```

Errors:

```
main.cs(27,48): error CS1061: Type `char' does not contain a definition for `Contains' and no extension method `Contains' of type `char' could be found. Are you missing `System.Linq' using directive?
```

Comment: Just `alphabetUpper.Contains(charItem)` is the correct condition if you use a `List<char>`... ultimately `countUpper = myPassword.Count(alphabetUpper.Contains);` and you don't even have to write the loop yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Any()` method should rather be like below cause `charItem` itself is pf type `char` and you are essentially trying to match it with a value in a char array

```
alphabetUpper.Any(x => x == charItem)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
foreach (char charItem in myPassword)
{
   if (Char.IsUpper(charItem))
   {
       countUpper++;
   }
}
```

You don't need the array.

Comment: Or even `countUpper = myPassword.Count(Char.IsUpper);` ... assuming that he wants the built-in definition of `IsUpper` which may contain uppercase versions of foreign characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following block to return the validation of the password. **Also**, i would change the return type of the validation function from `string` to `bool`

```
return myPassword.Length >= 6 && myPassword.Length <= 24 &&
                myPassword.Any(x => alphabetUpper.Contains(x)) &&
                myPassword.Any(x => alphabetLower.Contains(x)) &&
                myPassword.Any(x => digits.Contains(x)) &&
                myPassword.Any(x => symbols.Contains(x)) &&
                myPassword.Where((c, i) => i > 0 && c == myPassword[i - 1]).Count() == 0;
```

This code block validates that the password has at least one occurence from each of the arrays. (one lowercase, one uppercase, one digit and one special character) along with length to be more than 5 and less than 25. It also checks to make sure there is no repeating characters in the string.

You also dont have to use any loops with this linq statement.

Repeating Character function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18134818/1390548)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loop variable is a `char`, you can just compare it directly to the characters in the arrays using the `==` operator:

```
if (alphabetUpper.Any(c => c == charItem)) countUpper++;
```

One thing you might want to do, however, is loop through the items using a `for` loop so we can check for repeating characters by accessing the item at the next index in the char array (assuming that by "repeating character" you mean the character following the current character is the same).

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myPassword.Length;i++)
{
    var charItem = myPassword[i];

    if (alphabetUpper.Any(c => c == charItem)) countUpper++;
    else if (alphabetLower.Any(c => c == charItem)) countLower++;
    else if (digits.Any(c => c == charItem)) countDigits++;
    else if (symbols.Any(c => c == charItem)) countSymbols++;

    // Here we can check if this is a repeating character by accessing
    // the previous character using the 'i' index and subtracting one
    if (i > 0 && myPassword[i - 1] == charItem) repeatingCharacters = true;
}
```